# c++ multithreading - trying to make non-const objects const

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, sfml

I have a c++, sfml program and upon trying to implement multi threading have ran into a problem. First off I have little experience with multi threading. When I go to assign the thread tasks it is throwing 22 new errors all relating to objects being const but the objects are not const. Thanks.
sorry if the title is poorly worded.

here's some code to look over

```cpp
class NewKey {
public:
    sf::Image Img;
    sf::Texture Tex;
    sf::Sprite Sprite;
    sf::Vector2i Velocity;
    sf::Vector2i Acceleration;
    sf::Vector2i NextPos;
    bool isMovingLeft() {
        if (Velocity.x < 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    bool isMovingRight() {
        if (Velocity.x > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    void velocityCap() {
        if (Velocity.x >= 130)
            Velocity.x = 130;
        if (Velocity.y >= 130)
            Velocity.y = 130;
        if (Velocity.x <= -130)
            Velocity.x = -130;
        if (Velocity.y <= -130)
            Velocity.y = -130;
    }
    void loseSpeed(int x) {
        if (isMovingLeft()) {
            Acceleration.x += x;
        }
        else if (isMovingRight())
            Acceleration.x -= x;;
    }
    void StepVelocity() {
        Velocity += Acceleration;
        Acceleration = sf::Vector2i(0, 0);
    }
};

void foo() {
    NewKey Key;
    std::thread thread1;
    std::unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow> window = std::make_unique<sf::RenderWindow>(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::None);
    Key.NextPos = Gravity(Key, window, thread1);
    thread1.join();
}

sf::Vector2i Gravity(NewKey& Key, std::unique_ptr <sf::RenderWindow>& window, std::thread& thread1) {
    int windSpeed = 2;
    int dropRate = 10;
    thread1 = std::thread([=] {
        if (Key.Velocity.x == 1)
            Key.loseSpeed(1);
        else
            Key.loseSpeed(windSpeed);
        Key.StepVelocity();
        Key.velocityCap();
        if (Key.Velocity.y < 10 && Key.Velocity.y > 0) {
            Key.Velocity.y = 0;
        }
        });
    sf::Vector2i Result = sf::Vector2i(window->getPosition() + Key.Velocity);
    return Result;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

the errors

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "NewKey::loseSpeed" Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    61  
Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "NewKey::loseSpeed" Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    63  
Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "NewKey::StepVelocity"  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    64  
Error (active)  E1086   the object has type qualifiers that are not compatible with the member function "NewKey::velocityCap"   Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    65  
Error (active)  E0137   expression must be a modifiable lvalue  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    67  
Error   C3861   'Gravity': identifier not found Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    53  
Error   C2662   'void NewKey::loseSpeed(int)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const NewKey' to 'NewKey &'  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    61  
Error   C2662   'void NewKey::loseSpeed(int)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const NewKey' to 'NewKey &'  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    63  
Error   C2662   'void NewKey::StepVelocity(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const NewKey' to 'NewKey &'  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    64  
Error   C2662   'void NewKey::velocityCap(void)': cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const NewKey' to 'NewKey &'   Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    65  
Error   C3490   'y' cannot be modified because it is being accessed through a const object  Error   C:\Users\Jacob Krumholz\source\repos\FallingKeys\Error\Error.cpp    67
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the error messages verbatim.

Comment: I see *no* synchronization between threads in your code. That's a major red flag.

Comment: sorry that was in my main code must have missed it when singling out error

Comment: As a shot in the dark can you change the lambda capture in the Gravity function from = to &

Comment: nope same errors thanks tho

Comment: This question needs a [mcve].  Can you update your question to have a code sample that everyone can locally compiler themselves?

Comment: @Jacob Are you sure?  In function `Gravity` change `thread1 = std::thread([=] {` to `thread1 = std::thread([&] {`.  You might also want to tag/highlight the lines mentioned in the error messages.

Comment: Variables captured by-copy by the lambda expression are `const` and you have implicit by-copy capture in `std::thread([=] { ... })`. `Key` becomes `const` inside the lambda and you cannot call any non-`const` method on it.

Comment: uh ya sorry that fixed it. Thanks guys.